# StreamBuilder don't reload automatically, need hot reload the app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I've seen multiple questions about this but nothing helped me.

I have a StreamBuilder that look to a variable in Firestore, and this variable is use for a second StreamBuilder to get some text with an index.

When i update the variable on Firestore, the display of the variable is refreshed, but the texte is not, I need to hot reload or use the setstate() function.

I try to make a StreamSubscription for listening if the variable is update and call the setstate but that didn't work. I try calling setState in the StreamBuilder but I can't and even with `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) { })`.

Here my codes :

Stream for getting the variable

```
Stream _getIdDay() {
var stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Others')
    .doc('Variables')
    .snapshots();
return stream; 
}
```

Streambuilder for showing the variable

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _getIdDay(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
             _idDay = snapshot.data['id_day'];
             return Text("$_idDay");
         } else {
             return Text("$_idDay");
         }
    },
),
```

Stream for getting the text

```
Stream _getQuestionAndDate(int idDay) {
    var date = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Questions')
        .doc("$idDay")
        .snapshots();
    return date;
}
```

StreamBuilder for showing the text

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _getQuestionAndDate(_idDay),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            _question = snapshot.data['Question'];
            return Text(_question);
        } else {
            return Text(_question);
        }
    },
),
```

Comment: `StreamBuilder(
    stream: _getIdDay(),StreamBuilder(
    stream: _getIdDay(),`  NEVER build the stream in the stream: parameter of your StreamBuilder.  See this video for why: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: Ok I see I'll fix this but that won't solve my problem, will it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to solve the problem.

Since I need to call the setState function or hot reload the app for my StreamBuilder to get the new text, I put a ValueNotifier on my index variable, and on the initState, I create a listener so when the variable change, I call the setState function.

I don't know if it's a good solution or no, but it's working, tell me if it's not and how I can improve that.

My new code :

```
final ValueNotifier<int> _idDay = ValueNotifier(1);


@override
void initState() {

  _idDay.addListener(() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  });

  super.initState();
}
```

access to the value with `_idDay.value`